# rip mp3 rhythmbox

Tags: rhythmbox

I can't rip mp3 music in rhythmbox

error

Additional software is required to encode the multimedia files to your favorite format:
MPEG-1 Layer 3 (MP3) encoder

then

The parameters passed to the application have an invalid format. Please report a bug!

Parameters were:

```
- transient-for = 56623107
gstreamer | 1.0 | rhythmbox | MPEG-1 Layer 3 (MP3) encoder | encoder-audio/mpeg, mpegversion = (int) 1, layer = (int) 3
```

thanks

Answer (score 1):

open your terminal and type as

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

then try again.

More information: [Ubuntu Community Restricted Extras](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CDRipping)

Comment: I had already done. still does not work. thanks

Comment: You still  getting  the same  error